# Stacking cards one below the other in iOS

Tags: ios, swift

I am a newbie in iOS application development and I am trying to make a BlackJack game. I want to know how can I make a card appear one below the other one dynamically.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you thought the following line of code?

```
[parentView.subviews objectAtIndex:0];
```

or another option could be the following:

you can use the zPosition property of the view's layer (it's a CALayer object) to change the z-index of the view. The default value of this property is 0. Changing the value of this property changes the front-to-back ordering of layers onscreen ([Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CALayer/zPosition))

```
theView.layer.zPosition = 1;
```

Apart from all, there is quite well tutorial which explains all fundamental topics amd may address many other potential issues you may face along the way: http://www.objc.io/issue-12/animations-explained.html